# Obtaining values in a PHP left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I am trying to achieve is I have a company table that has 2 userid field (userid and updated userid) I am trying to use left join to get the 2 names from the UserTable here are the structure of my tables

```
[CompanyTable] 

CompanyID

UserID:int

UpdatedBy:int

[UserTable]


UserID:int

FullName:string
```

I got 1 working but can't get the second value. Here is the code I am trying to do.

```
SELECT company.CompanyID, company.UserID, company.UpdatedBy, users.FullName
    FROM company 
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.UserID = company.UserID
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.UserID = UpdatedBy.UserID
    GROUP BY company.CompanyID
```

Comment: May try to set an alias
`LEFT JOIN users as users1 ON users1.UserID = company.UserID
    LEFT JOIN users as users2 ON users2.UserID = UpdatedBy.UserID`

Comment: Can u do me a sample sorry haven't done MySQL for ages cheers

Comment: `SELECT company.CompanyID, company.UserID, company.UpdatedBy, users1.FullName, users2.FullName
    FROM company 
    LEFT JOIN users as users1 ON users1.UserID = company.UserID
    LEFT JOIN users as users2 ON users2.UserID = UpdatedBy.UserID
    GROUP BY company.CompanyID`

Like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below. The Idea is to JOIN the same `users` table twice with different alias and use them while selecting the fields. You have 2 ids in the company table and you can use the column alias to make it more readable for example `u2.FullName as FullName_UpdatedBy` means the full name of the updated by user.

```
select
c.CompanyID,
c.UserID,
u1.FullName,
c.UpdatedBy,
u2.FullName as FullName_UpdatedBy
from company c
left join users u1 on u1.UserID = c.UserID
left join users u2 on u2.UserID = c.UpdatedBy
group by c.CompanyID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not JOIN the same table twice with the same name, you will have to use Aliases:

```
SELECT company.CompanyID, company.UserID, company.UpdatedBy, u1.UserID, u2.UserID AS UpdatedBy
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.UserID = company.UserID
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.UserID = company.UpdatedBy
GROUP BY company.CompanyID
```